# Get listView item number from selected item in wpf and c#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listview, kinect

I have a ListView of images and i would know which image is selected from left click mouse.
I don't find any way to do this and i'm blocked on this code where it's impossible cast ListViewItem to Image for obtain index in list.

c#:

```
private void listView_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var hitTestResult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(listViewExercise, e.GetPosition(null));
    var selectedItem = hitTestResult.VisualHit;

    while (selectedItem != null)
    {
        if (selectedItem is System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem)
        {
            break;
        }
        selectedItem = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(selectedItem);
    }
        Image image = (Image)selectedItem;
    Console.WriteLine(image.Source);
}
```

XAML:

```
<k:KinectRegion x:Name="ChoiceExercise" Background="Black" >
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <k:KinectUserViewer Grid.Row="0" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ScrollViewer k:KinectRegion.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True" k:KinectRegion.IsScrollInertiaEnabled="true" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Row="1" >
                <ListView Grid.Row="1">
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <Viewbox Width="300" >
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Images/la.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300">
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill"  Source="Images/end exercise win.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300">
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Images/la.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300" >
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill"  Source="Images/end exercise win.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300" >
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Images/la.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300">
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Images/end exercise win.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300" >
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Images/la.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300">
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Images/end exercise win.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300" >
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Images/la.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300">
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill"  Source="Images/end exercise win.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300">
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Images/la.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300" >
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill"  Source="Images/end exercise win.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300" >
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Images/la.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300">
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Images/end exercise win.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300" >
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Images/la.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Width="300">
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Images/end exercise win.jpg"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </ListView>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</k:KinectRegion>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way to obtain the item container, and once you do that, you just need to extract the `DataContext` to get the item from the `ItemsSource`:

```
private void listView_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var source = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
    if (source == null)
        return;

    var selectedItem = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement((ItemsControl)sender, source)
                       as FrameworkElement;

    if (selectedItem == null)
        return;

    var image = selectedItem.DataContext as Image;
    if (image != null)
         Console.WriteLine(image.Source);
}
```

Comment: @luca that means the DataContext is not of type Image, so the relationship between ListViewItem and the Image is unclear here. I doubt that you have some itemtemplate for the ListView and Image is just an element inside it. So you should post more code (especially XAML code) to make it clear.

Comment: i have tryied this method but i obtained an exception because image is null(datacontext is viewbox and not image)

Comment: @luca so try this `(selectedItem.DataContext as Viewbox).Child as Image`

Comment: perfect i obtain the source (i will try to use it as index of list) but i have a small problem. Mouse up event selects below  pointer image and not which i had clicked and when i tap on image, list scroll so the method return near image name

Comment: Maybe the `Click` event isn't what you should be handling.  Perhaps you want to run some code when the `SelectedItem` changes on the `ListView`?

Comment: i would know which image is selected from the list, all I need to know is the index or name. I don't know if in one second moment i will need a list of item selectioned .
Now using SelectionChanged and SelectedItem obtain one element correctly, if i want multiselection? Is there one api or i must implement by code(by SelectedItems and added i one border or other for show elements selected) ?